# Why does probing Higgs self coupling provides information on *dynamics* of Electroweak Symmetry Breaking?

Tags: higgs, symmetry-breaking, bosons

Why does probing Higgs self coupling provides information on *dynamics* of Electroweak Symmetry Breaking ?

Also, Why does probing *Higgs self coupling* provides information whether Higgs boson is elementary or a Cooper pair ?

Comment: source? where did you read that?

Comment: Isn't the dynamics of SSB *defined* by all Higgs couplings beyond the mass term? You are asking about the name? What is your favorite Landau-Gizburg effective model for BCS?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Here is the reference: page 2 of : https://indico.cern.ch/event/835066/contributions/3625910/attachments/1955126/3247409/Grojean_IP_2019_12_03.pdf

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos : I don't master the subject (but I know Higgs physics). Do you mean that mass term is "static" and coupling is dynamic ? Why ? I don't master supraconductivity, but I know that cooper pair modelize it theoretically speaking. Would study of Higgs self coupling really explain if the Higgs is elementary or a cooper pair ? Is cooper pair meaning the same as "composite" ?

Comment: Yes, Cooper pairs may represent composite Higgs. Christoph G has written superb Higgsless reviews. Read them.

Comment: All right, thank you

Comment: Here: [Contino 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4269) and [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_Higgs_models).

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos : thank you